# How to remove or hide target files from Spring Boot maven project?

Tags: java, spring, git, maven, spring-boot

I created a **Spring Boot(Maven)** project in **STS(Spring Tool Suits)** and for sharing I used **Bitbucket**. But at the time of commit I saw so many **target files** in **Git Sharing popup**. I committed all files with target files. But when my friend pull that project then he found conflicts in that target files.
 
Then I created a new project but this time I committed only **"src"** file not target file then there is no conflict issue. But when the project is going big then there is lots of target file coming in Git Sharing window. And select my **src** from the multiple target file this is a kind of headache for me. So tell me how to remove or delete these target files permanently from my project.

> pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.ued</groupId>
    <artifactId>video_app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>video_app</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId> <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId> 
            <version>2.7.3</version> </dependency> -->


        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- To Compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- To Compile JSP -->

        <!-- Mail Starts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mail Ends -->

        <!-- Gson Converter Starts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Gson Converter Ends -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

> Image of Git Sharing window

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4O40.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a .gitignore file on the project root (parallel to `pom.xml`) and add `/target/` in a separate line.

A sample .gitignore file when spring boot project generated from https://start.spring.io/

```
/target/
!.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar

### STS ###
.apt_generated
.classpath
.factorypath
.project
.settings
.springBeans
.sts4-cache

### IntelliJ IDEA ###
.idea
*.iws
*.iml
*.ipr

### NetBeans ###
/nbproject/private/
/build/
/nbbuild/
/dist/
/nbdist/
/.nb-gradle/
```

Comment: Now I am using same .gitignore file and put all the above content in that file. But till now these target file **Category.class - targert/classes/io/ued/models** didn't remove from git Sharing and I have also used ***.class** in .gitignore file. How to resolve this?

Comment: This might happen when you have already check-in that file once in the repository. Once deleting from repository, it should not be there